# jquery LI's anchor hover problem [JSFiddle inside]

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Please see the JSFiddle for a pretty clear idea of the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/PeYYZ/

The above sort of does what I want. When I hover over `li.parent`, the `ul.child` menu fades in, which is fine. I want the sub menu to remain open, unless the user selects another `li.parent`. I tried messing with `mouseleave`,but I don't think that's what I'm after.

The logic I need is:

1. if user hovers over a `li` with
   class    `parent`, show it's
   `ul.child`
2. If the user then moves the mouse to    somewhere else that
   **isn't** a    `li.parent`, the `ul.child` should    remain open.
3. if the user moves to another    `li.parent`, then that `li.parent ul.child` should open, and the previously open one should
   disappear.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nzFZ6/ I had to edit the CSS part too.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MFZ8Q/

The key was selecting only links that are direct descendants of li.parent, then just making sure they are visible.

Hopefully this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Nice solution too, don't know which one is faster... Btw you shouldn't use `hover()` if there's no `mouseout` handler.

Comment: Good point Capsule, I've now updated mine to just use .mouseenter() http://jsfiddle.net/MFZ8Q/1/. Thanks.